# Logging custom events in the Firebase Analytics console (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to log custom events for my location rating app (Swift). After looking through examples it looks like you give attributes a value similar to a JSON database. I still haven't seen the event named logged in the analytics console (it's been about a week).It doesn't have any debug errors. Here is the instance:

```
FIRAnalytics.logEventWithName("Ratings", Parameters[
    "rating": (indexPath.row + 1)
```

Any advice?

Comment: Did you try to turn on the debug mode by using the argument -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled? It should show you whether the events were logged successfully.

Answer (score 14):

Its really late but it may help someone

```
 Analytics.logEvent("Ratings", parameters: [
        "rating" : (indexPath.row + 1)
        ])
```

FIRAnalytics is replaced with Analytics and logEventWithName is replaced with logEvent

Answer (score 5):

The syntax for logging a custom event in Swift would be:

```
FIRAnalytics.logEventWithName("Ratings", parameters: [
  "rating": (indexPath.row + 1)
])
```

Make sure that part of your code is getting executed by setting a break-point. Perhaps it's not being run.

Comment: Forgot to put that on here, but I did close the arguments there the way you showed. Still am not getting anything.

Answer (score 3):

```
import FirebaseAnalytics
```

Example code:

```
Analytics.logEvent("share_image", parameters: [
  "name": name as NSObject,
  "full_text": text as NSObject,
])
```